# How to write a method that takes int variables and returns the largest?

Tags: java, compare, max

I am trying to write a method that compares 3 numbers and returns the largest of them.

This is my code, but it doesn't work...

```
public int max(int x, int y, int z){
    return Math.max(x,y,z);
}
```

How can my code be corrected?

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```
public int max(int x, int y, int z){
    return Math.max(x,Math.max(y,z));
}
```

The method `Math.max()` only accepts 2 arguments, so you need to perform this method twice if you want to compare 3 numbers, as per the code above.

Answer (score 4):

For your current solution of 3 integer arguments, you could replace:

```
Math.max(x,y,z)
```

with

```
Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z)
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28int,%20int%29) shows that `Math.max` takes 2 arguments.

Comment: For the given problem of 3 instances, this is the easiest way to do it. I like the general solutions as well, but for this particular question I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

For any number of int values, you can do this (tip 'o the hat to zapl):

```
public int max(int firstValue, int... otherValues) {
    for (int value : otherValues) {
        if (firstValue < value ) {
            firstValue = value;
        }
    }
    return firstValue;
}
```

Comment: Further to the above, if you're using an older JVM version that doesn't support varargs (Java 1.4 or earlier), the method signature should be `public int max(int[] values)`, and you'll need to thus pass in an array

Comment: @WATTOStudios - Yes, varargs was introduced in Java 5, so it's been around a long time. There are still some Java environments (such as BlackBerry) that are Java 1.4.

Comment: yeah just wanted to mention it, you can never tell what the user is actually running. Love your answer though.

Comment: Changing the method signature to `public int max(int value0, int... values)` would make the `IllegalArgumentException` superfluent and maxValue could be initialized directly with `value0`. So much faster / smaller code :)

Comment: @zapl - Done! Much better to move error checking up to compile time. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

If Apache Commons Lang is on your classpath, you can use `NumberUtils`.

There are several `max`, `min` functions. Also one you wanted.

Check API: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html

Commons Lang is useful as it extends standard Java API.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JDK api:

```
public static int max(int i, int... ints) {
    int nums = new int[ints.length + 1];
    nums[0] = i;
    System.arrayCopy(ints, 0, nums, 1, ints.length);
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    return ints[nums.length - 1);
}
```